# Are there no polynomials in $\mathbb{C[x]}:f^2 − Xf = −X^2 + 1$?

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

Are there no polynomials in $\mathbb{C[x]}:f^2 − Xf = −X^2 + 1$?

What I did:
$$
f^2 − Xf = −X^2 + 1 \iff f^2=Xf-X^2+1
$$
$\deg(f)=n \rightarrow \deg(f^2)=2n$, $\deg(Xf)=n+1$ and $\deg(-X^2+1)$=2

So
$$
2n\leq\max(n+1,2)
$$
If $2\geq n+1$ then $\max(n+1,2)=2$ so $2 \geq 2n \Longrightarrow 1\geq n$.

if $n+1 \geq 2$ then $\max(n+1,2)=n+1$ so $n+1 \geq 2n \Longrightarrow 1\geq n$.

From that I conclude $\deg(f)=n=0 \vee \deg(f)=n=1$.

So I try $f=ax+b$.

After doing all the calculations (hard to type) I got:

$$
a^2-a=-1;2ab-b=0;b^2=1
$$
Which makes an incompatible system, so I conclude there exists no polynomials that satisfy the initial conditions.

Is this correct? Did I screw up somewhere?

Side question:

Why do people sometimes seem to write polynomials with a big $X$ instead of the little one? I've seen this happen in algebra classes and some websites.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: There's nothing deep about using $X$ or $x$ in a polynomial, just the author's preference.

Comment: People sometimes like to use capital letters for indeterminates and lower-case for values in the field.

Comment: Thus if you're working over the field $\mathbb Z_p$, $x^p = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z^p$, but $X^p \ne X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over any field not of characteristic $2$ or $3$, write your equation as
$$\left(f - \dfrac{X}{2}\right)^2 = 1 - \dfrac{3 X^2}{4}$$
So the right side must be the square of a polynomial, and clearly that
polynomial would have to be of degree $1$.  But $(a + b X)^2 = a^2 + 2 a b X + b^2 X^2$ would have a term in $X$ unless $a=0$ or $b=0$, and neither of those work (either the degree-$0$ term or the degree-$2$ term would be missing).

BTW, in characteristic $3$ there is a solution $f = 1 + X/2$; in characteristic $2$ there is again no solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what characteristic 2 or 3 mean, I haven't yet studied that.

Comment: If all you know are the real and complex numbers, don't worry: those have characteristic $0$.